# Tag synonym [shapefile] and [shp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I suggest that [shp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shp) should be a synonym of [shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapefile).

They both are used in questions about the Esri shapefile geo data format, there are 733 questions tagged with [shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapefile) and another 84 tagged with [shp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shp).

The description for [shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapefile):

> The Esri shapefile or simply a shapefile is a popular geospatial vector data format for geographic information systems (GIS) software.

The description for [shp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shp) is very similar:

> A file format created by ESRI to save geospatial information. It is the default file format in ArcGIS and other ESRI software for saving geometries. Because the file format specification is open it is widely supported in other GIS software as well. Shapefiles consist of a .shp, a .dbf and a .shx file. While the .shp contains the geometry, the other files contain meta data.

Comment: Claiming a three-letter acronym has a high demand, you have to have IBM or PHP chops.  Looking through the [shp] question list, I see plenty of them that don't have anything to do with an ESRI product.  Not a good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant The file format was developed by ESRI as an open standard, and anyone is free to use it. Neither [shp] nor [shapefile] are and should be about ESRI software exclusively. It is used widely in many other, often free and open source, software these days.

Comment: Then I suppose the first thing you'll have to do is edit the tag wiki.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok thank you, I placed an edit suggestion just now. I just noticed that the GIS Stackexchange has it already synonymized (see [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/shapefile/info)).

Comment: How about avoiding this mess altogether and just retagging those questions?

Comment: I have now retagged them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All 84 questions have been retagged to [shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapefile).